# how to add scrollbar for a dropdown inside the fixed navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, scroll

I am using navbar (bootstrap 3) as the main navigation menu in my website and I have couple of dropdown menus on it (some of them filled with the fixed data , some data is coming from database) , I want to have a Y-scrollbar for inside each dropdown , so without changing anything in my navigation bar when user click on drondown it show the limited data with ability to scroll to see the rest

All ideas are greatly appreciated.
here is my code :

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" >
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            @if (Html.HasAssetContext())
            {
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", Html.HasAssetContext() ? "Asset" : "Home")"><i class="icon-home"></i></a></li>
            }
            @if (Html.HasPermission(Category.SEARCH) && (Html.HasCompanyContext() || Html.IsClient()))
            {
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-search"></i>Search <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        @Html.MenuLink("Systems", "Index", "System")
                        @Html.MenuLink("Machines", "Index", "Machine")
                        @Html.MenuLink("Components", "Index", "Component")
                        @Html.MenuLink("Exceptions", "Index", "Exception")
                    </ul>
                </li>
            }
            @if (Html.HasPermission(Category.ORDER) && Html.OrderModuleEnabled())
            {
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-briefcase"></i>Order <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        @Html.MenuLink("Customers", "Customers", "Order")
                        @Html.MenuLink("Machine Orders", "MachineOrders", "Order")
                    </ul>
                </li>
            }
            @if (Html.HasAssetContext())
            {
                if (Html.HasPermission(Category.REPORT))
                {
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-file-text"></i>Report <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            @Html.MenuLink("Exception Charts", "Index", "Chart")
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            @Html.MenuLink("PM Compliance By Machine", "MachinePmCompliance", "Report")
                            @Html.MenuLink("PM Compliance By Component", "ComponentPmCompliance", "Report")
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            @Html.MenuLink("MTBE By Machine", "MachineMeanTimeBetweenException", "Report")
                            @Html.MenuLink("MTBE By Component", "ComponentMeanTimeBetweenException", "Report")
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            @Html.MenuLink("Cost Benefit Analysis", "CostAnalysis", "Report")
                            @Html.MenuLink("Asset Hierarchy", "AssetHierarchy", "Report")
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                }
                if (Html.HasPermission(Category.DOCUMENT))
                {
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Documents", "Document")"><i class="icon-file"></i>Documents</a></li>
                }
                if (Html.HasPermission(Category.DATA_ENTRY))
                {
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-list"></i>Data <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            @Html.MenuLink("Identification Reports", "IdentificationReports", "Report")
                            @Html.MenuLink("Component Checklist", "ComponentChecklist", "Data")
                            @Html.MenuLink("Manage Engineers", "Engineers", "Data")
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                }
            }
            @if (Html.HasCompanyContext() || Html.IsClient())
            {
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-anchor"></i>Assets <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    @Html.AssetMenuLinks()
                </li>
            }
            @if (Html.HasPermission(Category.SELECT_COMPANY))
            {
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-building"></i>Companies <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    @Html.CompanyMenuLinks()
                </li>
            }
            @if (Html.HasPermission(Category.ADMINISTRATION))
            {
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-cog"></i>Admin <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        @Html.MenuLink("Companies", "Companies", "Administration")
                        @Html.MenuLink("Assets", "Assets", "Administration")
                        @Html.MenuLink("Users", "Users", "Administration")
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        @Html.MenuLink("Applications", "Applications", "Administration")
                        @Html.MenuLink("Bearings", "Bearings", "Administration")
                        @Html.MenuLink("Departments", "Departments", "Administration")
                        @Html.MenuLink("Environments", "Environments", "Administration")
                        @Html.MenuLink("Faults", "Faults", "Administration")
                        @Html.MenuLink("Manufacturers", "Manufacturers", "Administration")
                        @Html.MenuLink("Severities", "Severities", "Administration")
                        @Html.MenuLink("Techniques", "Techniques", "Administration")
                        @Html.MenuLink("Templates", "Templates", "Administration")
                        @Html.MenuLink("Work Order Statuses", "WorkOrderStatuses", "Administration")
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        @Html.MenuLink("Import Data", "ImportData", "Administration")
                        @Html.MenuLink("Audit History", "AuditHistory", "Administration")
                    </ul>
                </li>
            }
            @if (!Html.IsClient())
            {
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Info")"><i class="icon-info"></i>Info</a></li>
            }
        </ul>
           </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It sounds like you should override the behavior of a bootstrap div. You should load a custom .css file after bootstrap's css. You refer to the correct div (sorry, i am not too familiar with bootstrap) and set a fixed height to it. Also make sure to activate the scrolling by setting `overflow-y:scroll;` on the same div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in my comment, import a custom css file after the bootstrap one and try something like:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  max-height:150px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks, but I already have done that the issue is when I override its behaviour the whole structure of my navbar is ruined!

Comment: the dropdown menu is opened inside the narvar (runinng the navbar height)  rather than drop drown as usual with the scroll bars

Comment: Thanks Roy , I found that where I was doing wrong your solution was totally correct , I added  max-height:150px;   overflow-y:scroll; in to the bootstrap.min.css file  and it is working just fine ( after couple of cache clearing !)

Comment: @Ghazaal: good to know it worked for you. So you added the custom rules to the end of the bootstrap.css file, which is totally fine. The reason I would prefer separate custom CSS definitions, is that it will survive an update to the next version of bootstrap. It is common practice with all libraries.